# What causes the background hissing in car speakers?

Tags: automotive

My knowledge of electronics is very limited, but I think I should be able to understand the answer to this. 
In a car, if I turn the volume up as high as it goes with the auxiliary cable plugged in, I can get a constant, quiet, hissing noise to come out of the speakers. What causes that "static"? Rogue current flows, the air touching the male end that's sticking out, or other things I just am not thinking of?

Comment: This might be a great question for the [Audio Video Production Stackexchange](http://avp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.analog.com/en/content/raq_lownoiseamp/fca.html) is an article that explains where the noise comes from you are hearing. This is the detail below but some formulas have not been extractable from the source so read the source.

> Resistor Noise can be Deafening, and Hard to Reduce
>
> Q. My low-noise amplifier is not low noise enough. What am I doing
>   wrong?
>
> A.  It may not be the amplifier causing the trouble; analyze where the
>   noise is actually coming from. A typical operational amplifier circuit
>   contains six uncorrelated noise sources (the smaller ones can usually
>   be disregarded1). The amplifier itself has three separate noise
>   sources: a voltage noise source appears differentially across the
>   inputs; and current noise sources appear in series with both inverting
>   and non-inverting inputs. Remarkably often the problem is not the
>   amplifier, though, but the thermal noise generated by one or more of
>   the three resistors that set the amplifier gain and provide bias
>   current compensation. Analog Devices has over sixty types of op amps
>   whose voltage noise is less than that of a 1 kΩ resistor .
>
> This answer is rarely popular; it is far more satisfactory to blame an
>   imperfect amplifier and replace it with a better one than to admit
>   that there is a fundamental problem with apparently simple components
>   such as resistors. In fact, a remarkably common response to a
>   diagnosis of resistor noise is to seek a source of "good" resistors,
>   with "good" being defined as without thermal noise.
>
> This is impossible. The basic physics of resistance shows2 that the
>   random thermal movement of charge carriers in a conductor always
>   produces electrical noise of value  where k is Boltzmann's Constant
>   (1.38065 x 10-23 J/K), T is the absolute temperature, B is the
>   bandwidth and R the resistance. (We often express this noise in terms
>   of spectral density, making the voltage noise .
>
> Such noise is known as thermal noise, or Johnson noise, after John B.
>   Johnson (Bell Telephone Laboratories – 1928), who was the first person
>   to observe it. It might more properly be named Johnson/Nyquist noise
>   as it was Harry Nyquist (also at Bell Laboratories) who explained the
>   physical basis of Johnson's observation.
>
> So anywhere at all that there is resistance in a circuit, whether it
>   is carrying current or not, there is a noise generator with an output
>   voltage noise spectral density of . We can reduce the noise by
>   reducing the resistance (this may increase current and/or power
>   consumption), but reducing the temperature is not usually practicable
>   (if we cool a resistor from room temperature (298K) to liquid nitrogen
>   temperature (77K), its noise voltage is still more than half its room
>   temperature value). And, of course, we can't change Boltzmann's
>   Constant because Professor Boltzmann is dead3.
>
> 1 Any noise source less than 1/3 the magnitude of the largest can be
>   ignored for most practical purposes.
>
> 2
>   http://www.physics.utoronto.ca/~phy225h/experiments/thermal-noise/Thermal-Noise.pdf
>
> 3 Died 5 September 1906 at Diuno near Trieste, buried Zentralfriedhof,
>   Vienna.